# Running applications in Run and RunOnce Registry programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have developed a custom shell written in WPF/C# that replaces explorer.exe as the shell on a Windows 8.1 system.  Everything runs fine, except I would like to run the applications in the Run/RunOnce registry locations.  The main issue is that there seems to be no standard way of putting the entries in the registry - some have double-quotes around the entries, some don't; some are run through rundll32 and have an entry point defined followed by comma-separated arguments; some have space separated arguments; some have a few executables in one entry.
Is there a service or executable I can call to run these entries, or am I stuck trying to figure out a way to parse this as best as possible and using Process.Start()?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for a project at work. The following code is more-or-less what I wrote. I can't guarantee that it's foolproof but it seemed to work with the registries I tested against.

```
public static class ProcessHelper
{
    const string RegistrySubKeyName =
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";

    public static void LaunchStartupPrograms()
    {
        foreach (string commandLine in GetStartupProgramCommandLines())
        {
            string fileName;
            string arguments;

            if (File.Exists(commandLine))
            {
                fileName = commandLine;
                arguments = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (commandLine.StartsWith("\""))
            {
                int secondQuoteIndex = commandLine.IndexOf("\"", 1);
                fileName = commandLine.Substring(1, secondQuoteIndex - 1);

                if (commandLine.EndsWith("\""))
                {
                    arguments = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    arguments = commandLine.Substring(secondQuoteIndex + 2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int firstSpaceIndex = commandLine.IndexOf(' ');
                if (firstSpaceIndex == -1)
                {
                    fileName = commandLine;
                    arguments = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    fileName = commandLine.Substring(0, firstSpaceIndex);
                    arguments = commandLine.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1);
                }
            }

            Process.Start(fileName, arguments);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetStartupProgramCommandLines()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key =
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistrySubKeyName))
        {
            foreach (string name in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                string commandLine = (string) key.GetValue(name);
                yield return commandLine;
            }
        }

        using (RegistryKey key =
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegistrySubKeyName))
        {
            foreach (string name in key.GetValueNames())
            {
                string commandLine = (string) key.GetValue(name);
                yield return commandLine;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, this looks phenomenal.  It doesn't need to be foolproof at the  moment.  I'll take a run through it and see how this will fit into my codebase.  You rock!